# In postgres is it safe to (mis)use a temporary (session-local) sequence as a transaction local sequence?

Tags: postgresql, database-design, transactions

I want to have a counter that i will reset to 0 every time a new transaction begins. I want the value of that counter to be used in some triggers. Since postgres temporary sequences are session local i can use one as my counter only if there is no possibility of 2 transactions running in "parallel" in the same session. Is this safe to assume in Postgres? (What I have in mind that makes me feel unsure is a situation like the autonomous transactions in Oracle. In that scenario my session local object would be shared by outer transaction and the inner autonomous transaction which would ruin the transaction locality of the object I want.)

I know that I can use a TEMP table with ON COMMIT DROP or DELETE ROWS, but i would like to know if a temp sequence would suffice, at least in postgres.

Comment: So what exactly is your question? "Is it safe?" is not specific enough. What do you want to achieve?

Comment: I d like to know if a session local object can be accessed by more than 1 transaction at the same time in any possible way. I described in more detail the context of my question. Sorry if not clear.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Currently PostgreSQL has no support for parallel or autonomous transactions, so session == transaction and thus a session-local temporary sequence will to be accessed only by one transaction at a time.

The only way you can simulate autonomous transactions in Pg at the moment is by using dblink to make a new connection to the database. As that also establishes a new and independent session,  you don't have anything to worry about from dblink.

Currently, it's safe (if I've interpreted what you want correctly).

In the long run there is a desire to introduce autonomous transactions as part of true stored procedure support. That looks like it's a long way off, and it's not clear whether an autonomous transaction would be able to see temporary tables and sequences created by its parent anyway. You'd have to wait and see, and be prepared to adapt your approach accordingly, perhaps by using a temporary sequence named after the current transaction id (txid).

You could do that now if you wanted; use the `txid_current()` function to get the current transaction ID.

Edit: Nope, txid doesn't change across savepoints.

```
regress=> begin;
BEGIN
regress=> SELECT txid_current();
 txid_current 
--------------
       346947
(1 row)

regress=> savepoint test;
SAVEPOINT
regress=> SELECT txid_current();
 txid_current 
--------------
       346947
(1 row)
```

though I guess that is relying on an implementation detail.

Comment: I though of that, but i didnt do it because i had the impression that txid changes with savepoints. Isnt this true?

Comment: @Paralife: Also, operating with dynamic identifiers makes it hard to use features like column defaults or non-dynamic SQL.

Comment: txid doesn't change across savepoints - see above. If you were worried about that, you could build an identifier from the txid and the CURRENT_TIMESTAMP (as that's fixed at txn start). [Edit: that's nonsense; the txid would still change. You can't use _just_ the timestamp in case two txns start at the same time down to timer resolution. Ugh. Just rely on txid not to change, and test upgrades well!]

I don't think this will ever be particularly pretty, but you can wrap it up in a simple SQL function to make it easier to use in defaults and in non-dynamic SQL as Erwin mentions that as a concern.